# Call function when hidden element is shown

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to call a function on the controller when a ng-show sets to true and an previous hidden element is visible? I need a directive to run a function when the element it is inside goes from hidden to visible.

```html
  <div ng-show="showOrNot" >
  This is secret text.
  <my-directive> I need to call a function </my-directive>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use ng-init to call function.

Comment: No. Its not trigered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ng-init** to call function and use **ng-if** here is example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Demo',['$scope', Demo]);
function Demo($scope){
  $scope.showOrNot = false;
  $scope.Show = function(){
    $scope.showOrNot = true;
    alert("shown");
  }
  $scope.hello = function(){
    alert("function call!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Demo">
<div ng-if="showOrNot">
  <div ng-init="hello()">This is secret text.</div>
</div>
  <button ng-click="Show()">click</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the `showOrNot` scope to your directive's scope. Then `$watch` it and add the desired logic after the value changes.

Simply:

```
<my-directive value-to-watch="showOrNot">I need to call a function</my-directive>
```

Then the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    scope: {
      valueToWatch:'='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.$watch('valueToWatch', function (newValue, oldValue) {
          //Case when new value is true and old value is false
          if(newValue && !oldValue) {
             //Call the function you want
          }
       });
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $watch in your controller inorder to call a function when it is true.

```
  <my-directive content="showOrNot"> I need to call a function </my-directive>

.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      content: '=',
    }
    link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.$watch('content', function (newvalue, oldvalue) {
       if(newvalue == true)
       {
          //your function here
       }
     });
     }
  }
}
```

you can write something like this.